# config module in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie with angujar.js and I want to develop a simple application which change content using some html files like [this example](http://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend)

Is my **config** wrong? What else do I have to do?

index.html

```
<html ng-app="main">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    Some title
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js">
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- app -->

</html>
```

main.js

```
var mymain = angular.module('main',[]);

mymain .config(  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'otherfile.html',
        controller: 'F'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

mymain.controller('F', function($scope) { 
    alert("here");    
});
```

otherfile.html

```
<span>Something else...</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

Do I have to have angular.js on a server(at least localhost) ? my code for route works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/geb5fh1Ns4fZC5XDOvaV?p=preview) but not when I just open my file with a browser.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Are you asking us to _review_ the code or _solve a problem_ with it?

Comment: @SeanDoe how can I see those errors?

Comment: It depends of browser you use, but predominantly pressing F12 shows debug console

Comment: @DavinTryon I'm just asking for help, at least a hint to make it works.

Comment: @Andres: Davin is asking you because you didn't say anything about what happened when running the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JB Nizet** was right, I needed

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

But I also needed

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The router is not part of the core angular.js file. It's a separate module that must be declared in your main module dependencies. It's also in a separate JS file, that must be added to the index.html file, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).

Comment: I added `angular-resource.min.js` but it does not still work, what else should I to?

Comment: You must add the 'ngResource' module in the dependencies of your app, as explained in the documentation. Read it.

Comment: Do I have to have angular.js on a server(at least localhost) ? my code for **route** works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/geb5fh1Ns4fZC5XDOvaV?p=preview) but not when I just open my file with a browser.

Comment: Yes, I don't think using the route api on file URLs would work.